# compare start "Time" is less than the end "Time" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a value in two text fields which is already formatted as hh:mm, How can I compare the values of these two fields?

I am trying the following code:

```
function check_ToFromTime(toTime) {
    if (getControl('txtStartTimeFrom').value == '00:00' && getControl(toTime).value == '00:00') { return true; }
    var fromDate = new Date(getControl('txtStartTimeFrom').value);
    var toDate = new Date(getControl('txtEndTimeTo').value);

    var fromT = fromDate.getTime();
    var toT = toDate.getTime();
    return (toT >= fromT);
}
```

the if statement in the first line works, but the last statement
     return (toT >= fromT);
does not work. it always returns false. where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about converting these `String` objects to `Date` objects.  Just split the string and compare:

```
var fromDate = "04:05";
var toDate = "04:04";
var fromTokens = fromDate.split(":");
var toTokens = toDate.split(":");
alert(fromTokens[0] < toTokens[0] || (fromTokens[0] == toTokens[0] && fromTokens[1] < toTokens[1]));
```

You could place this functionality in a nice function for re-usability:

```
function isAfter(fromDate, toDate){
  var fromTokens = fromDate.split(":");
  var toTokens = toDate.split(":");
  return (fromTokens[0] < toTokens[0] || (fromTokens[0] == toTokens[0] && fromTokens[1] < toTokens[1]));
}

//Tests
alert(isAfter("04:04", "05:05"));
alert(isAfter("06:04", "05:05"));
alert(isAfter("05:05", "05:05"));
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/X5v5F/

I'm not going to head down this route, since I think splitting the strings is sufficient, but if you were fixed on a date, I would recommend using Moment.js.

Comment: There's no need to split the string as 04:05 evaluates less than 04:06

Answer (score 0):

it will always print false because end time will always be greater than start time.U need to change the condition i.e. return (toT <= fromT);